# ランダムで生成したオブジェクトをdestroyする方法

Tags: c#, unity3d

ランダムで生成したオブジェクトをdestroyする方法

下記のようにオブジェクトを配列に入れてランダムで生成しています

```
int enemyIndex  = Random.Range( 0, m_enemyList.Length );
var enemyObject = Instantiate( m_enemyList[ enemyIndex ], new Vector3( 0, 3, 0 ), transform.rotation ) as GameObject;

var background2  = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag( "background" );
enemyObject.transform.SetParent( background2.transform, false );
```

生成したオブジェクトをdestroyで削除したいのですが、ランダムで生成したオブジェクトをdestroyする方法はありますでしょうか

Comment: 状況が分からないので具体的なアドバイスはできないですが、敵のHPは敵自身が管理するべきですし、そのために問題が生じてる場合はまずそれを解決する必要があります。enemystatus.csがアタッチできないのはスクリプト自体に問題があるかMonoBehaviourを継承してないとか理由があるはずですが、例えば enemy.csというMonoBehaviourを継承した「敵クラス」を作ってその中でenemystatusを保持するとかして、Destroyも敵クラスが制御することを目標に進めてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: アタッチできるのは MonoBehaviourを継承したクラスだけです。enemy statusが普通のクラスならば、public enemystatus Enemystatus = new enemy status(); とすればそのまま使えるはずです。

Comment: アタッチは不要ではないかと思っていますが、もう本来の質問から大きく外れてしまっているのでこの件についてはこれ以上はコメントを控えます。分からない点、意図した通りに動作してない点を今一度まとめ直して、改めて質問するのがいいと思います。混乱させてしまって申し訳ございませんでした。

Answer (score 3):

生成したオブジェクトを List で保持しておいて後でまとめて破棄する方法もありますが、生成するのが敵のようなので、敵のスクリプトの中で自滅する方が簡単かと思いました。（敵に何かしらのスクリプトが付いてる前提です）

```
    // 敵スクリプト内で不要になったタイミングで破棄
    Destroy(gameObject);
```

不要になった瞬間に破棄するのが問題な場合は時間指定で破棄することもできるようです。

```
    // 敵スクリプト内で不要になったタイミングで、１秒後に破棄
    Destroy(gameObject, 1.0f);
```